# Order by numbers last

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a neo4j database which has nearly 500k `CK_ITEM` nodes defined as follows:

```
CK_ITEM: {
    id (String),
    name (String),
    description (String)
}
```

Suppose we have this sample data:

```
+--------+----+-----------------+
|  name  | id | description     |
+--------+----+-----------------+
| Mark   | 1  | A lot of things |
| Gerald | 9  | Coff2e          |
| Carl   | 2  | 1 mango         |
| James  | 3  | 5 lemons        |
| Edward | 4  | Coffee          |
+--------+----+-----------------+
```

I need to order the data by `description ASC`. This is my query:

```
MATCH (n:CK_ITEM)
ORDER BY
    n.description ASC
```

This results in:

```
+--------+----+-----------------+
|  name  | id | description     |
+--------+----+-----------------+
| Carl   | 2  | 1 mango         | <-- '1' < '5'
| James  | 3  | 5 lemons        | <-- '5' < 'A'
| Mark   | 1  | A lot of things | <-- 'A' < 'C'
| Gerald | 9  | Coff2e          | <-- '2' < 'e'
| Edward | 4  | Coffee          | 
+--------+----+-----------------+
```

Now, the customer asked me to order the results so that they are still in ascending order, but numbers are left last.

Basically he wants the results to be:

```
+--------+----+-----------------+
|  name  | id | description     |
+--------+----+-----------------+
| Mark   | 1  | A lot of things |
| Edward | 4  | Coffee          |
| Gerald | 9  | Coff2e          | <-- Coff2e after Coffee
| Carl   | 2  | 1 mango         | <-- 1 and 5 ASC after everything
| James  | 3  | 5 lemons        |
+--------+----+-----------------+
```

Translated to a pseudo-query, it would be something like this:

```
MATCH CK_ITEM ORDER BY letters(description) ASC numbers(description) ASC
```

Is it possible to have this kind of sorting (letters first ascending, numbers last ascending) in a single query? How?

Comment: 1) Write a neo4 plugin to sort the collection; OR 2) Add an index for sorting, in which to replace the numbers with guaranteed unused symbols, but which go at the end when sorting

Comment: To add to @stdob's list of options: (3) if you are making the Cypher query programmatically: don't sort at all in your Cypher code, but perform the custom sort in your client code -- after you get the Cypher results.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a Cypher query that will perform a sort where digits come last (at every character position).

*NOTE: THIS APPROACH IS NOT EFFICIENT, but is presented as an example of how to do this in Cypher if you absolutely needed to.*

The query splits every `description` value into single-character strings, tests each character to see if it is a digit, constructs a new string (character by character) -- replacing every digit with a corresponding UTF-16 character in the hex range `FFF6` to `FFFF` (these are the highest possible UTF-16 character encodings, and your raw data is unlikely to already be using them), and uses that new string for sorting purposes.

```
WITH {`0`:'\uFFF6',`1`:'\uFFF7',`2`:'\uFFF8',`3`:'\uFFF9',`4`:'\uFFFA',`5`:'\uFFFB',`6`:'\uFFFC',`7`:'\uFFFD',`8`:'\uFFFE',`9`:'\uFFFF'} AS big
MATCH (n:CK_ITEM)
WITH n, SPLIT(n.description, '') AS chars, big
RETURN n
ORDER BY
  REDUCE(s='', i IN RANGE(0, LENGTH(chars)-1) |
    CASE WHEN '9' >= chars[i] >= '0'
    THEN s + big[chars[i]]
    ELSE s + chars[i]
    END)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can order this way:

```
MATCH (n:CK_ITEM)
   RETURN n
ORDER BY
    substring(n.description,0,1) in ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'], n.name
```

Comment: `substring(n.description,0,1)` - this takes just the first character, I need the sort to work for every character. The data I posted is a sample, the sort needs to work just with the `description` field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reqular expression and UNION:

```
MATCH (n:CK_ITEM) WHERE NOT n.description =~ '[0-9].*'
RETURN n
ORDER BY
    n.description ASC

UNION

MATCH (n:CK_ITEM) WHERE n.description =~ '[0-9].*'
RETURN n
ORDER BY
    n.description ASC
```

Comment: This seems to take just the first character too. I need the sort to work for every character, regardless of its position, just as the normal sort does